# adding java spark code unit testing in the build fat jar fails the spark run later

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark

I try to add unit test code for some java spark method. However, I found the spark job run failed after I add them. Here are the things I found

a) After I added the unit test code, they will be run when I build the java fat jar.

b) Then, after build, if I ran the spark submit job, it will failed with the exception below

```
 Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 7000ms
java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
......
```

c) To fix this issue, I have to remove the metastore_db folder under the code root directory.

d) If I don't build the jar again, but directly run the spark job (after fix the issue in step c), then, it will run fine.

Based on what I see above, my guessing is that the unit test during the building jar process started a spark session (something like that). And this session is not being closed. Therefore, when the actual code run later, the job will failed to have a new session connection.

Again, this is my guessing. Below is my unit testing code.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setMaster("local[2]");
    conf.setAppName("sparkHelperTest");
    sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sparkContext);
    sparkHelper = new DSERunEnvironmentSparkHelper(sparkContext, sqlContext, aktanaServiceConfiguration);
}
                                                       
@Test
public void testAccountDF() {
    ArrayList<Account> mockList = new ArrayList<>();
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setId(1);
    account.setName("name");

    List<StructField> listOfStructField= new ArrayList<>();
    listOfStructField.add(DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false));
    listOfStructField.add(DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true));

    StructType structType=DataTypes.createStructType(listOfStructField);


    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(mockList).map(
            account -> RowFactory.create(repAccount.getId(), account.getName());

    DataFrame df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, structType);
    df1.show();
}

@After
public void postProcess () {
    sparkContext.stop();
    sparkContext.close();
}
```

Another notice is that let's see if I fix the metastore_db issue by c). If I build the fat jar and run the job again, it still fail. However, if I run the unit testing directly (NOT re-build the jar) and run the job again, the job is running OK. So the testing run in the build failed the spark job, while the directly running unit test through IntelliJ is OK.

Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you exclude the tests from your fatjar? How do you submit your code to the cluster? Have you tried without the postProcess() method?

Comment: @jgp, thanks for replying. The tests code is part of the build process. CICD process is in charge by another team. Not sure that's an option. I didn't manually submit the code to any cluster. That's the mystery to me. I initially doesn't have the postProcess() method. But after I observe the issues above, I then adde it.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out. The issue is caused by running the build jar using sudo and spark job using normal user. It seems that the db.lck file being created cannot be used shared by 2 users.